Inherit --import in Nodejs VM.Context
On nodejs 21
npm i -D tsx
node --import tsx src.ts

This works perfectly transpiling source code on-the-fly. Including whatever es module expretions like
import {Something} 'mod'
export const what = 'ever'

Still trying to run a ts source in the vm withing the same env
import {runInContext, createContext} from 'vm'

runInContext(`
export const a = 'some'
`, 
createContext({...}),
)

fails with
export export const a = 'some'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

even trying previously to compile manually ts source
import {runInContext, createContext} from 'vm'
import * as ts from 'typescript'

runInContext(
ts.transpileModule(`
export const a = 'some'
`, {...}).outputText, 
createContext({...}),
);

with whatever target, module, moduleResolution till fails with different yet all the way syntax errors similar to
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined

So please what would be the proper way to make the vm to reuse the same importer defined with --import rsx for the host context?
Or at least to compile properly the source manually so that it handled correctly within the vm env?
Thank you.
